# Adding all the numbers in the firebase and store it in a variable in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a collections with field of rating and i want to iterate through the collection and add all the values. Finally i want to store it in a variable that can be accessed by all screen in flutter.

Any idea?

Here what i have tried so but failed

```
void calculateHomeTeamRating(){
    int rating=0;
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('SelectedPlayersHome').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData){
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final players = snapshot.data.docs;
        List<int> homeRating = [];
        for(var playerRating in players){
          rating = rating + playerRating.get('Rating');
        }
        String textRating = rating.toString();
        homeRating.add(rating);
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the collections and the fields that shows the player name and their rating:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model class to encode and decode incoming data from firestore and can use this model class to store data.

##### Create class to store player data.

```dart
class Player {
  String playerName;
  int rating;
  String timestamp;

  Player({this.playerName, this.rating, this.timestamp});

  Player.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    playerName = json['PlayerName'];
    rating = json['Rating'];
    timestamp = json['timestamp'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['PlayerName'] = this.playerName;
    data['Rating'] = this.rating;
    data['timestamp'] = this.timestamp;
    return data;
  }
}
```

##### Pass `QuerySnapshot` to `calculateHomeTeamRating` function and it will returns the `List<Player>` and use it accordingly. .

```dart
Future<List<Player>> calculateHomeTeamRating(
      QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) async {
    final List<Player> playerList = [];

    final data = querySnapshot.docs;
    if (data != null && data.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var model = Player.fromJson(querySnapshot.docs[i].data());
        playerList.add(model);
      }
      return playerList;
    } else {
      return null;
      
    }
  }
}
```

##### use specific value(rating) from list  of player

```dart
var List<int> ratings;

final players = snapshot.data.docs;

final list = calculateHomeTeamRating(players);

if(list!= null && list.isNotEmpty){
  ratings = list.map((player)=> player.rating).toList();
}

if(ratings!= null && ratings.isNotEmpty){
  print("Total given ratings: ${ratings.length}");
}
```

Comment: What if in the snapshot i just want to access specific field (which is rating) and loop it to get the total of it?

Comment: From my understanding, this way, I can access the rating for each player and add it to List<int> ratings. So, how do I get the cumulative of all the players rating? By cumulative I mean to add all the rating and store it into totalRating. Sorry a bit confusing for me and thanks for the help.

Comment: You can get sum of all ratings from this code. var sum = ratings.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

Comment: Bro, if i want to access the list in other flutter page, what should i do?

Comment: You can pass the list in the constructor of other page or by using state management technique it can be used any where in app.